# How to Render StencilJs components in ASP.NET-CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, stenciljs, stencil-component

I've created a few web components using StencilJs and published them to npm. How to use these component s in ASP.NET core?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stenciljs.com/docs/hydrate-app. Your question is not really specific enough, imo.